# How can i data frames to different worksheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm currently working on a code that scrapes a website for football match data, and I want it to put the data tables from the last 5 seasons into one excel workbook but on different sheets for each season.

The code below works fine until the point where it actually has to create the excel workbooks. Currently, it creates 5 different workbooks, one for each id, but only the ids 1631 and 1889 contain the correct data. The other three workbooks contain the data from id=1889.

I already looked up several solutions, but couldn't find one that matches my problem, so I'm not entirely sure if it even can be done.
**Thank you in advance!**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

def get_df(team_name, team_id):

    seasons_url = (
        f"https://fbref.com/de/mannschaften/{team_id}/2021-2022/{team_name}-Statistiken",
        f"https://fbref.com/de/mannschaften/{team_id}/2020-2021/{team_name}-Statistiken",
        f"https://fbref.com/de/mannschaften/{team_id}/2019-2020/{team_name}-Statistiken",
        f"https://fbref.com/de/mannschaften/{team_id}/2018-2019/{team_name}-Statistiken",
        f"https://fbref.com/de/mannschaften/{team_id}/2017-2018/{team_name}-Statistiken",)

    ids = ["stats_standard_11160",
           "stats_standard_10728",
           "stats_standard_3232",
           "stats_standard_1889",
           "stats_standard_1631"]

    heads = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                           '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}

    for season in seasons_url:
        url = season
        response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
        html = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        for id in ids:
            tables = (soup.find(id=id))
            if tables is not None:
                table = tables

            for table_per_season in table:
                df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{team_name}{id}.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{id}", index=True)
                writer.save()
```

Comment: can you share an id and team_name so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is this bit of code:

```py
if tables is not None: 
    table=tables
```

First, if  `tables` is `None` on the first time then you have an error `table is called before assignment`.

But more importantly, if `tables` is `None` during the loop, it will not tell you it didn't get the data but will just write the previous value of `table` which explains why you have several time the same data.

Depending on what you expect from your function, you could put the writing part in the `if` condition so it writes only when you found data and print a message otherwise.